# Color changing of the window title bar

Tags: macos, customization

Is it possible to change the color of the window title bar (possibly with Terminal.app) like in Firefox?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a GUI, then [CrystalClear](http://www.marsthemes.com/crystalclear/) might be for you. However, it is a bit outdated. [Geektool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) is another great alternative, however you will have to find the modules yourself.